# Proof that $\bar D(-1,\frac14)$ lies inside the Mandelbrot set

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, complex-dynamics

I am currently compiling proofs of the most elementary properties of the Mandelbrot set $M$.

For example :

- $M\cap\mathbb{R}=[-2,\frac14]$
- $\bar D(0;\frac14)\subset M$.
- $M\subset\bar D(0,2)$
- $c\in M\implies K_c\subset\bar D(0,2)$ (where $K_c$ denotes the filled Julia set associated to $c$)

Those proofs are very simple and involve essentially the triangle inequality.

> I would like to know if I can expect an elementary proof for : $\bar D(-1,\frac14)\subset M$.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set#Main_cardioid_and_period_bulbs it is the set of parameters $c$ for which $z^2+c$ has an attracting cycle of period 2 – is that elementary enough?

Comment: @Martin R - I do agree that knowing this, the conclusion follows immediately. But I don't know if it is easy to prove. It would be sufficient to prove that if c lies in the open disk $D(0,\frac14)$, then the sequence defined by $z_0=0$ and $z_{n+1}=z_n^2+c$ has its two subsequences $(z_{2n})$ and $(z_{2n+1})$ both convergent to some limit. Or even to prove that $(z_n)$ is bounded. In the case $\vert c\vert \leqslant\frac14$, it is straightforward to show that $\vert z_n\vert\leqslant\frac12$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.